# receive sms from my application in android from special number

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, development-environment

I want my program to be able to receive sms from a special number("+9856874236"). But, if the SMS is from any other number, it should go to the phone's message inbox and not to my application.

please help me my dears

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
      public String str = "";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // ---get the SMS message passed in---

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

            if (bundle != null) {

                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) 
                {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                    //for get sms from special number===============================
                    String msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    Log.v("msg_from >>",msg_from);     
                    if(msg_from.equals("+9830007546"))
                    {
                        //===============================
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    str += " :";
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";    
                    Intent act = new Intent(context, ReceiveSMS.class);
                    act.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    act.putExtra("message", str);
                    context.startActivity(act);

                    this.abortBroadcast();
                    }

                }
                // ---display the new SMS message---
                // Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            }
    }
```

main class :

```
     private TextView showSms;
 private String   ReceivedSms;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //this.setContentView(R.layout.receivesms);
     /*Removing system bar from screen*/
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.receivesms);
    Intent act = getIntent();       
    ReceivedSms = act.getStringExtra("message");
    showSms = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    showSms.setText(ReceivedSms);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your `BroadcastReceiver` a high priority in your `AndroidManifest`. This will put your receiver first in line to process the broadcast.

```
<receiver 
    android:name=".SmsReceiver">                        
        <intent-filter
            android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Inside your `BroadcastReceiver`, check if the number of the incoming sms equals your given number. If true, then cancel the broadcast with `abortBroadcast()`.

**Edit**

There are a couple of things to watch out for:

- When you do the number matching, be aware of phone number formatting. If the incoming number is `0123456789` and you use `String.equals('+XX0123456789')`, then your check will fail, even though its technically correct. Have a look at [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html) to find a solution for this.
- If I recall correctly, some device manufacturers have given the default SMS application priority one on processing sms broadcasts. This will mess with your application. Be sure to test this out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant to say that your special number should not show up in the inbox...

You cannot re-route the message being received by the phone. So instead you have to upon receiving that message then look it up in the MMS database and delete it, there is no other way.